# Convert strong font to normal font in panada

Tags: python, dataframe

Image :

[image]

I am analyzing the twitter hashtag data. But I find there are special font for some words, e.g. FOLLOW in the figure. How to convert into normal font?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what kind of font that is, but you can overwrite the font-family of your DataFrame:

```
df = df.style.set_properties(**{
    'font-family': 'Times New Roman'
})
```

That should format the entire DF to Times New Roman (or any other font that you like, e.g. see [here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_websafe_fonts.asp)).